# Manipulating google form responses into a timeline

Tags: forms, date, google-sheets, formula, repeat

[Info from Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgD7o.png)[Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTK4R.png)We use a Google form for activity planning purposes, some activities repeat weekly. Rather than having to submit a form each week so it appears as a new activity on the timeline, is there a way to duplicate the activity on sheets, and add it as a reoccurring activity every Tuesday for example?
I added a question to the form, is this a repeat activity, if so is it every (Monday, Tuesday, etc) but now don't know how to use that information to duplicate the activity on sheets with dates or if this is even possible.

Comment: Hi, In order for us to better understand what values we are working with can you share a minimum reproducible copy of your Google Sheet?

Comment: Hi George - I hope I have uploaded 2 images showing what I mean

Answer (score 0):

### Repetitive Task Auto Add:

Hi! I understand that you are trying to create automation in accordance with your repetitive events. I would like to start by sharing with you that the solution you are looking for is beyond Google Sheets capability alone. So what I suggest is using Google Apps Script along with it. I created a Google Apps Script you can add on your Google Sheets that will automatically run every day and it will automatically detect task or events that will be repeated and re write it on the last row of your data in Google Sheet given that all the repetitive task have values on Column J.

### Sample Code:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('processEvents').timeBased().everyDays(1).create();
} //This script will run every task below everyday

function processEvents(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1") // Please change it accordingly depending how your Sheet was named.
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 1, ss.getLastColumn());
  var eventData = range.getValues();
  var dateToday = new Date();
  var dateTodayName = dateToday.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });
  for (var i = 0; i < eventData.length; i++) {
    if (eventData[i][9] !== "") {
      var daysToRepeat = eventData[i][9];

      var daysToRepeatArr = daysToRepeat.split(",");

      for (var j = 0; j < daysToRepeatArr.length; j++) {
        if (daysToRepeatArr[j] == dateTodayName) {

          var dataTobeCopied = eventData[i];
          var additionalRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, dataTobeCopied.length);
          additionalRange.setValues([dataTobeCopied]); // The block of code let's it compare what are the repetitive task during that it was called.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would also like to share that the solution provided might not completely give you the exact solution you are looking for due to limited information about your expected result, but this is going to be good starting point and will put you on the right direction.

### Reference:

[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)

[Time Driven Events Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thank you Babanana - Unfortunately, this is beyond my capabilities, I tried adding it as suggested but not really sure what I am doing but I cannot get it to work. However I just wanted to say thank you for responding.

Comment: I am so sorry to hear that, no worries what you can do instead is start with the basics of Google Apps maybe read about it a little bit more, so that you can understand how the block of code works. If you have a history with programming languages I am pretty sure that it will be easy for you to understand it. For tutorials I really suggest utilizing YouTube guides event though it is a little bit old, just to get some foundation of it.